# Rails Twitter API 取得した値をDBに保存

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webapi

現在Railsアプリを作成中です。

TwitterAPIを用いてUser情報を取得しているのですが、検索をして返って来た結果をユーザが保存するなどのボタンを押した上でDBに保存をしたいのですが実装は可能でしょうか?(スクリーンネームを保存しようと考えています)

[image: イメージ図]

Answer (score 0):

- 技術的には、実装は可能です。データとしてアプリ側に渡ってきているものは、何であれ適切に処理すればデータベースなどの他サービスに渡すことができます。
- これより詳しい具体的な実装については、質問の中に具体的な実装が含まれていないのでなんとも言えません。具体的に困っているポイントについて、コードと共に別の質問としてご投稿いただけますでしょうか。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます! 別の質問と言う形であげさせてもらいました。